# Is there a way to disable ng-repeat with a click of a button?

Tags: angularjs

I have ng-repeat on an element that repeats through items in a list "mylist".
Is there a way in javascript to "disable" the ng-repeat on that element if mylist exceeds a particlar size? Or a means if I click on a button, the list's ng-repeat behavior will get disabled or point to a different list so that I don't get performance issues if a user adds 50,000 items to the list?

Comment: I've found that for large lists that cause ng-repeat issues, it's better to create your own directive that builds the table for you.  50,000 elements will bring your site to it's knees with ng-repeat as it has to check every item every digest.

Comment: What does it mean to "disable"? Do you not want to render the `ng-repeat`-ed elements and render something else? or do you want to render the first N elements only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually change what you are repeating at any time (for instance reduce `mylist` if t gets too big), or you can simply use `limitTo` to limit the number of items repeated:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mylist | limitTo: myLimit">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.myLimit = 50;
```

You can then add a button to "load more" that would only do `$scope.myLimit += 50` for instance (or do that when the users scrolls down the list, which is usually called "infinite scrolling").

Comment: Would this help with performance such that 50,000 items would not be "watched"/hit performance issues.

Comment: Yes, that would only create 50 items in the DOM and only them would have watchers. The performances would be way better!

Comment: Want to limit to 10. Any more than that, no.

Comment: You can directly write `limitTo: 10` or do like I showed you `limitTo: myLimit` with `$scope.myLimit = 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the entries displayed by ng-repeat by using the `limitTo` filter. You can find more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Although there would be no indication that the limit has been reach and not all of the elements are being displayed. You would need to implement that yourself. The `limitTo` filter only limits from the first element, you cannot get view subsections of the array.

Another alternative would be to use a virtual scrolling directive. Something like: https://github.com/EnzeyNet/VirtualScroll

Comment: Would this help with performance such that 50,000 items would not be "watched"/hit performance issues.

Comment: Correct, the idea behind virtual buffering is that only the rows visible on the screen are watched. The scroll bar makes it look like you have all of the items in the list when in fact only the items that fix within the view are currently rendered and watched. Once those rows are scrolled out of view the watches are removed.